# Поиск повторяющихся элементов в большом массиве

Tags: java

Есть массив строк (`String[]`) размером в один миллион, и надо найти те строки, которые повторяются.
Но при поиске стандартным методом (цикл в цикле) все это занимает очень много времени.
Как лучше это реализовать? И можно ли уложиться в 10 секунд?

Answer (score 6):

Очень просто, но с дополнительными расходами памяти:

- Взять set (множество) – контейнер, обеспечивающий быстрый (логарифм..константа) поиск по значению и не допускающий (возможно, игнорирующий) вставку одинаковых значений.
- При обходе массива (в одном цикле, без вложенности) поддерживать два множества (изначально пустых): одно со строчками что встречались ранее, второе со строчками что встретились больше одного раза (иначе говоря, с ответом).

Что будет происходить на каждой итерации в процессе обхода, предлагаю установить самостоятельно.

Увеличение расхода памяти вы можете почти и не ощутить, если хранить в множестве прямо те же строчки, что в массиве (а не копии) по ссылкам (как в Java хранятся все объекты). Если, конечно, у вас не совсем мелкие строки, но   чем больше в массиве дублирования, тем меньше попадёт в множества, так что даже с мелкими может быть всё не так плохо.

Comment: А разве `Set` подойдет? При каждой вставке он будет проверять есть ли такой или нет. Под конец операции вставки будут очень медленными

Comment: @Flippy при использовании реализации Hashset поиск, вставка удаление выполняются за константное время не зависимо от размера.

Comment: @temq, спасибо буду знать

Comment: Гарантированное надежное решение, которое не зависит от функции хеширования, это положить все строки в бор.

Comment: @pavel да, это одна из реализаций множества для строк. Но операции с ним логарифмические, хэшсет может оказаться пошустрее. Но алгоритму, в целом, пофиг, можно всё забенчмаркать и решить :)

Comment: @D-side а почему логарифмические?.. Как раз строго линейно все, вот только памяти будет использовано чуть больше (если массив переходов фиксированный делать)

Comment: @pavel ага, я почему-то проигнорировал то, что там строки, там каждое сравнение линейно, и в итоге выходит k*log(n). Множество на дереве будет делать много сравнений одинаковых префиксов, а бор как раз от этого позволит избавиться и делать О(k) {n число строк, k длина} Скрытая константа побольше, но на таком числе строк это должно окупиться, наверное.

Comment: @D-side но что-то у меня вариант с построением ДКА работает на порядок дольше, чем варианты с `HashMap` и с двумя `HashSet`. То ли я реализовал это криво, то ли для используемых мною строк такой подход плохо работает.

Comment: @Regent надо профилировать, чтобы дать однозначный ответ. Входной набор большой/длинный?

Comment: @D-side попытаюсь оптимизировать код в рамках используемого решения, но, сдаётся мне, с 2800ms до 250ms уменьшить всё же не получится. В качестве тестового набора строк использую миллион строк, первые 100к из которых уникальны, а остальные - их копии. Каждая строка - 20 символов с алфавитом charcode от 32 до 127. Думаю, всё же опубликую свои реализации и результаты замеров как ответов - заодно можно будет увидеть что не так с моим ДКА.

Comment: @D-side в общем, составил тест всего этого дела. Надеюсь, что обошлось без крупных ошибок в формировании массива, в алгоритмах и в замерах. С префиксным деревом/ДКА ситуация лучше не стала.

Answer (score 5):

**Тестовые данные**. Х строк, первые У из которых уникальны, а оставшиеся Х-У - копии этих У. Все строки одинаковой длины и состоят из символов с charcode-ами от 32 до 127.

```
private static final Random random = new Random();

private static String[] generateArray(int stringsTotalCount, int uniqueStringsCount,
        int stringLength)
{
    String[] array = new String[stringsTotalCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < uniqueStringsCount; i++)
    {
        array[i] = generateString(stringLength);
    }
    for (int i = uniqueStringsCount; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int index = random.nextInt(uniqueStringsCount);
        array[i] = new String(array[index]);
    }
    return array;
}

private static String generateString(int stringLength)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        int charCode = random.nextInt(96) + 32;
        sb.append((char)charCode);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Конечная цель**. Получение массива/списка/множества строк, которые встречаются в исходном массиве более одного раза.

**Первый алгоритм**. Сравнение строк с помощью цикла в цикле. Несмотря на оптимизацию (`j = i + 1`, `break`, `duplicates.contains`), алгоритм всё равно работает "за квадрат" (`O(n^2)`), что приводит ко времени работы в несколько минут.

```
private static void compare(String[] data)
{
    Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        if (duplicates.contains(data[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++)
        {
            if (data[i].equals(data[j]))
            {
                duplicates.add(data[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(duplicates.size());
}
```

**Второй алгоритм**. Использование `HashMap` для подсчета количества вхождений каждой строки с последующим выбором тех строк, для которых количество больше 1.

```
private static void oneMap(String[] data)
{
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String str : data)
    {
        if (!map.containsKey(str))
        {
            map.put(str, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);
        }
    }
    List<String> duplicates = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(duplicates.size());
}
```

**Третий алгоритм**. Использование двух `HashSet`: одного для уже найденных строк, второго - для хранения дубликатов.

```
private static void twoSets(String[] data)
{
    Set<String> foundStrings = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (String str : data)
    {
        if (foundStrings.contains(str))
        {
            duplicates.add(str);
        }
        else
        {
            foundStrings.add(str);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(duplicates.size());
}
```

**Четвёртый алгоритм**. Построение префиксного дерева / использование ДКА для определения, встречалась ли данная строка ранее.
**!** Возможно, реализация не является оптимальной. Отдельное хранение первой пары "символ - состояние" (`firstChar` и `firstState`) ощутимо ускоряет работу при случайных строках. При менее случайных строках прирост производительности может быть меньше.

```
private static class State
{
    private Map<Character, State> transitions;
    public boolean isFinal = false;
    private char firstChar = 0;
    private State firstState = null;

    public State get(char c)
    {
        if (firstState != null && firstChar == c)
        {
            return firstState;
        }
        if (firstState == null)
        {
            firstState = new State();
            firstChar = c;
            return firstState;
        }
        if (transitions == null)
        {
            transitions = new HashMap<>();
        }
        State state = transitions.get(c);
        if (state == null)
        {
            state = new State();
            transitions.put(c, state);
        }
        return state;
    }
}

private static void dfa(String[] data)
{
    State root = new State();
    Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (String str : data)
    {
        State state = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            state = state.get(c);
        }
        if (state.isFinal)
        {
            duplicates.add(str);
        }
        else
        {
            state.isFinal = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(duplicates.size());
}
```

**Пятый алгоритм**. Сортировка массива с последующим сравнением соседних элементов.

```
private static void sort(String[] data)
{
    Arrays.sort(data);
    Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i - 1].equals(data[i]))
        {
            duplicates.add(data[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(duplicates.size());
}
```

**Результаты тестирования**.

1. 1000k строк, 100k уникальных, длина строки 20

   ```
   compare    n/a ms
   oneMap     290 ms
   twoSets    280 ms
   dfa        670 ms
   sort       840 ms
   ```
2. 1000k, 500k, 20

   ```
   compare    n/a ms
   oneMap     860 ms
   twoSets    770 ms
   dfa       2060 ms
   sort      1300 ms
   ```
3. 1000k, 500k, 10

   ```
   compare    n/a ms
   oneMap     320 ms
   twoSets    240 ms
   dfa       2020 ms
   sort       810 ms
   ```

Указанные значения являются приблизительными средними значениями.
`n/a` означает, что программа работала больше минуты (`>60k ms`).

Comment: тут на самом деле есть проблема - вы не делаете *копии* строки. У вас просто копируется указатель. Используете честное копирование с созданием новой строки. Иначе даже хеш закешируется в самой строке. (Они тупо по == будут равны). Да и код dfa работает как-то сильно долго в случае 2 (явно что-то не так). Вот пример http://ideone.com/ZPTUoK на С++, я не использовал Map а просто массив, но вроде бы код одинаковый.

Comment: @pavel про жутко сомнительные результаты работы варианта с ДКА я писал ещё в комментариях к ответу D-side, но от первой версии реализации получилось повысить производительность только процентов на 10. Использование массива вместо `Map` не внушает оптимизма, ибо нужно будет рассчитывать алфавит, да и charcode-ы в нём не обязаны идти подряд: например, могут быть латинские буквы и кириллица. Насчет не использования настоящих копий строк - попробую с настоящими, но, надеюсь, результаты от этого не сильно изменятся.

Comment: предложу еще блум фильтр

Comment: @etki а что насчет ложных срабатываний? Получается, в случае положительного результата всё равно придётся сравнивать строку с уже просмотренными (например, как в третьем варианте).

Comment: @Regent а что, замена ссылок на честные копии, не ухудшила время работы других алгоритмов?

Comment: @Regent задача ничего не говорит об абсолютной точности :зефирчик:

Comment: @pavel ухудшила, на 10-40% в разных тестах, без учета погрешностей самих замеров. Изменения можно увидеть в 4й редакции ответа. DFA получилось разогнать за счет экономии памяти, плюс для таких рандомных строк как в тесте придумал ещё одну оптимизацию, ускоряющую работу раза в 3, но для менее рандомных строк прирост, думаю, будет куда меньше. Добавлю её в ответ, если ничего толковее не придумаю. Но `oneMap` и `twoSets` DFA всё равно получается не конкурент.

Comment: @etki будет несколько нечестно в соревновании использовать неточный алгоритм наряду с точными) Но попробую реализовать Блума - можно будет добавить результаты его работы, так сказать, "вне зачета".

Comment: @Regent А как Вы производили замеры времени работы?

Comment: @Lugovets всё сводится к замерам времени начала и конца работы алгоритма с помощью `System.currentTimeMillis()` и вычислению разницы между конечным временем и начальным. Конкретно в этой задаче ДКА (дерево) себя почему-то плохо показал, однако зачастую этот вариант работает быстрее других. Так было, например, в [этом случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/645622/183458) и [в этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656375/183458).

Comment: @Regent большое спасибо!