# Поиск строк из массива в строке

Tags: java

Есть строка:

`String text = " I hate spam."`

Также есть массив строк:

```
String[] keywords = new String[] { "spam", "spamer" };
```

Необходимо проверить, имеется ли в `text` такой же `"spam"` как и в `keywords`.

В каком направлении двигаться для решения задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим, что нужно проверять, содержится ли хотя бы одно ключевое слово (стоп-слово) в заданной строке.

Полный перебор ключевых слов с проверкой с помощью метода `contains`

```
private static boolean bruteForce(String text, String[] keywords)
{
    for (String keyword : keywords)
    {
        if (text.contains(keyword))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

прост в реализации и быстро работает при небольшой длине строки и небольшом количестве ключевых строк.

Однако при большом объёме данных этот алгоритм начинает работать достаточно долго.
При длине строки в миллион символов и 10 тысячах ключевых слов (длина каждого - 20 символов) у меня алгоритм работает 3100-3200мс при условии, что в строке есть только последнее ключевое слово в конце строки.

В этом случае можно, например, построить [ДКА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) на базе ключевых слов, после чего пользоваться им для поиска совпадений в строке.

Представленный ниже алгоритм отличается от [алгоритма Ахо - Корасик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%90%D1%85%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA) в плане обработки несовпадения подстроки, однако работает всё равно достаточно быстро (на тех же данных - 60-70мс).

При проверке множества строк на одни и те же ключевые слова имеет смысл построить ДКА один раз и в дальнейшем использовать его для всех строк. В таком случае время обработки для исходной строки снизится до 40-50мс.

Класс состояния ДКА с учетом оптимизации:

```
private static class State
{
    private Map<Character, State> transitions;
    public boolean isFinal = false;
    private char firstChar;
    private State firstState = null;

    public State get(char c)
    {
        if (firstState != null && firstChar == c)
        {
            return firstState;
        }
        if (transitions != null)
        {
            return transitions.get(c);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public State getOrCreate(char c)
    {
        if (firstState != null && firstChar == c)
        {
            return firstState;
        }
        if (firstState == null)
        {
            firstState = new State();
            firstChar = c;
            return firstState;
        }
        if (transitions == null)
        {
            transitions = new HashMap<>();
        }
        State state = transitions.get(c);
        if (state == null)
        {
            state = new State();
            transitions.put(c, state);
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

Формирование ДКА и поиск по строке:

```
private static boolean dfa(String text, String[] keywords)
{
    State root = new State();
    for (String keyword : keywords)
    {
        State state = root;
        for (char c : keyword.toCharArray())
        {
            state = state.getOrCreate(c);
        }
        state.isFinal = true;
    }
    State state = root;
    int foundSymbols = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        state = state.get(text.charAt(i));
        if (state == null)
        {
            i -= foundSymbols;
            state = root;
            foundSymbols = 0;
        }
        else if (state.isFinal)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            foundSymbols++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе человечище за такой развернутый подробный ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ! :)

`text.contains(String.valueOf(keywords[0]));`

ну а keywords, соответственно в цикл для перебора по индексу

Answer (score 0):

Для небольших объёмов данных можно использовать прямой перебор:

```
String text = " I hate spam.";
String[] keywords = new String[] {"spam", "spamer"};

// эту часть лучше вынести в отдельный метод
boolean isContains = false;
for (String s : keywords) {
   if (text.contains(s)) {
      isContains = true;
      break;
   }
}

if (isContains) {
   // слово содержится...
}
```