# Удаление повторов символов из строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка. Нужно составить регулярное выражение, которое при использовании в `replace` с заменой на пустую строку оставит в строке для каждого символа только его первое вхождение в строку. Как это сделать?

Пример. Вход - `"у попа была собака"`, выход - `"у поа был ск"`.

Comment: Вам надо, чтобы рядом таких символов не было или чтобы вообще только 1 раз встречался каждый символ.

Comment: второе. пример: вход - "у попа была собака", выход - "у поа был сбк"

Comment: Добавьте пример в вопрос

Comment: Обязательно ли это делать с помощью рег. выражения? И если все последующие вхождения буквы `а` удалены, то почему все пробелы (это ведь тоже символ) остались на месте? Буква `б`, кстати, дважды остается в вашем примере.

Comment: пробелы не важны, их вообще можно исключить все. да, обязательно регулярным

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первый вариант на основе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813516/3432401):

```
String str = "Упопабыласобака";
String result = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
result = result.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "");
result = new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Вывод на экран:

> Упоабылск

Замена `replaceAll("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "")` приводит к сохранению только последнего вхождения символа в строку, поэтому приходится разворачивать строку перед заменой и, соответственно, после замены.

---

Второй вариант без разворота строки, но с пометкой "не повторяйте этого дома", на основе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817660/3432401):

```
String str = "Упопабыласобака";
String pattern = "(.)(?=(.*))(?<=(?=\\1.*?\\1\\2$).+)";
String result = str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Вывод на экран аналогичен.

---

Третий вариант без использования рег. выражений (для полноты картины и для сравнения производительности) с использованием `HashSet`:

```
String str = "Упопабыласобака";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    if (!set.contains(c))
    {
        set.add(c);
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

---

Тест на строке из 10k символов (код генерации строки можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638437/183458)):

```
1:  220мс
2: 1250мс
3:    2мс
```

Тест на строке из 100к символов:

```
1:  19000мс
2: >60000мс
3:      5мс
```

Comment: великолепный ответ!

Comment: мне пойдёт и без реверса вывод, главное чтобы всех символов осталось по 1.  большое спасибо! 3й вариант не подходит, по условию нужно использовать regexp

Comment: @Артур на здоровье. Какой вариант использовать - право ваше. Если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с Java8 можно использовать Stream API (удаляются абсолютно все повторяющиеся символы):

```
String in = "у попа была собака";
String result = in.chars().distinct().collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.trim().replace(" ", "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    for (int i = 1; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        String ch = String.valueOf(sb.charAt(i - 1));
        while (sb.indexOf(ch, i) != -1) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.indexOf(ch, i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]