# Получить уникальные значения списка

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список:

```
var list = new List<string> {
    "строка",
    "строка22у", 
    "строкайцвцйй", 
    "текстцвцй", 
    "текст", 
    "текстыауке5"};
```

Нужно удалить элементы, которые содержат в себе другие элементы. Т.е. удалить строки `строка22у`, `строкайцвцйй`, т.к. содержат первую строку и `текстцвцй`, `текстыауке5` соответственно. В результате останутся `строка`, `текст`.

Делаю так:

```
int removedCount;
do
{
    removedCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        removedCount += list.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(list[i]) && x != list[i]);
    }
} while (removedCount != 0);
```

Есть ли более эффективный способ?

Comment: А чем текущий способ не устраивает? Вроде все лаконично и самое главное, что работает

Comment: @iluxa1810 - нет, код не работает. Добавьте в начало списка "строка1","строка3","строка4". Ошибка классическая - удаление из списка внутри цикла по нему.

Comment: Новый вариант стоит добавлять в конец вопроса, а не заменять им первоначальный.

Comment: @Igor, завернул еще в один цикл.

Comment: @Skrim - опять мимо: `removedCount += ...` внутри `for` и  `removedCount = 0;` перед `for`

Comment: @Igor да упустил. Поправил. Но как-то слишком много переборов получается или я не прав? Можно ли укоротить всю конструкцию?

Comment: @Skrim а вас вообще что интересует: быстродействие при большом количество элементов в списке или код покороче?

Comment: @Regent *"You want it fast or you want it good? We no rush. You no rush Michelangelo. You no rush Leonardo. You no rush a Finucci."* - "Оскар", в главной роли - Сильвестр Сталлоне.

Comment: @Regent быстродействие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При большом количество строк (особенно если многие из них имеют одинаковые префиксы) вариант с построением префиксного дерева и поиску по нему должен работать гораздо быстрее. Однако и кода выходит гораздо больше.

Вариант реализации. Метод поиска требуемых строк:

```
private static List<string> dfa(List<string> list)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    State root = new State();
    foreach (string word in list)
    {
        State state = root;
        foreach (char c in word)
        {
            state = state.get(c);
        }
        state.isFinal = true;
    }
    foreach (string word in list)
    {
        State state = root;
        int i = 0;
        for (; !state.isFinal && i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            state = state.get(word[i]);
        }
        if (i == word.Length)
        {
            result.Add(word);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вспомогательный класс состояния ДКА с учетом оптимизации:

```
private class State
{
    private Dictionary<char, State> transitions;
    public bool isFinal = false;
    private char firstChar;
    private State firstState = null;

    public State get(char c)
    {
        if (firstState != null && firstChar == c)
        {
            return firstState;
        }
        if (firstState == null)
        {
            firstState = new State();
            firstChar = c;
            return firstState;
        }
        if (transitions == null)
        {
            transitions = new Dictionary<char, State>();
        }
        if (transitions.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            return transitions[c];
        }
        State state = new State();
        transitions.Add(c, state);
        return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = list.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    if (list[j].Contains(list[i]) && list[i] != list[j])
    {
      list.RemoveAt(j);
      if (j < i)
        i--;
    }
  }
}
```