# Поиск строк в большом массиве по префиксу

Tags: java

Имеется большой отсортированный массив строк (100000 строк, каждая строка может иметь длину в 32 символа (латинские буквы и цифры)).
Вводим начало нужной нам строки.
Как реализовать **максимально быстрый** поиск нужной строки?

Как произвести индексацию строк, ведь пользователь может ввести и одну букву, и две, и пятнадцать, а доступно памяти только 64 MB?

Comment: Можно бинарным поиском, раз массив отсортирован (я так понял по алфавиту). Сначала ищешь ту половину, где есть строки, начинающиеся с первой буквы из строки, введенной пользователем. Затем, как наткнулся на такое слово (то есть отрезал все половины, где нет слов, начинающихся с этой буквы). Затем добавляешь вторую букву и ищешь тем же алгоритмом уже по две буквы и так пока не найдешь. Ну это алгоритм, который просто в мыслях пришел... Самый быстрый поиск в отсортированном массиве - бинарный.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov Получается тогда нет никакой индексации и при каждом поиске нужно выполнять большое количество операций

Comment: 100к строк - бинарно это 17 поисков (сравнений), быстрее вряд ли получится.

Comment: @Akina 17 поисков на первую букву, а если букв 25

Comment: @Lugovets Ну можно строить дерево, при каждом поиске дополнять его. Но ограничение по памяти может помешать. Надо проверять. В идеале можно попытаться еще до выполнения поиска, сразу после заполнения массива, построить дерево, но надо вычислять опять же потребляемую память.

Comment: *17 поисков на первую букву, а если букв 25* Ну можете построить индексный массив для первой буквы (или первых двух) и выбирать границы поиска одним индексным обращением - выиграете в среднем 4 поиска.

Comment: @Lugovets, если букв 25 в худшем случае будет 25 * 17 = 425 операций. Это же ничтожно мало.

Comment: @Akina Я тоже думал об этом. Если я построю индексный массив для первой буквы, то для второй буквы нужно делать свой массив строк (это массив в котором слова начинаются с первых двух введёных букв) и сортировать его?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov спасибо за идею! А как Вы видите логику построения такого дерева?

Comment: @Lugovets нужно думать, пробовать. Главное, что для каждой буквы нужно знать позиции, на которых с этой буквы начинается слово и ссылки на узлы со следующими буквами после этой

Comment: *Если я построю индексный массив для первой буквы, то для второй буквы нужно делать свой массив строк (это массив в котором слова начинаются с первых двух введёных букв) и сортировать его?* Это ещё зачем? в индексном массиве Вы для каждой начальной буквы храните индекс первого на эту букву и соответственно последнего элементов в своём сортиренном списке. И соответственно бинарный поиск выполняете не по всему списку (от 1 до N), а по его части (от Kmin до Kmax), в среднем по 1/25-й.

Comment: @Akina Да, но это для первой буквы. Для первой буквы наш массив строк отсортирован. А если я хочу индексный массив для второй буквы? ведь по второй букве нет сортировки.

Comment: @Akina И вдруг подберётся такой исходный массив строк, что все слова будут начинаться с одинаковой буквы..

Comment: Индексный массив исключительно по второй букве не имеет смысла, так как у вас поиск по префиксу. Для второй буквы нужно для каждой буквы индексного массива первых букв делать свой индексный массив вторых букв. Это в общем-то уже дерево начинает напоминать.

Comment: @iksuy да, я с Вами согласен, нужно думать как реализовать дерево. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lugovets можно, например, с помощью создания класса состояния ДКА (вершины дерева), в котором будут храниться переходы в другие состояния по определённым символам, а также, конкретно для этой задачи, варианты для отображения. Для формирования ДКА (дерева) нужно будет "скормить" изначальному, корневому пустому состоянию все имеющиеся строки. Моя реализация с учетом оптимизации по памяти периодически всплывает в моих ответах, и посмотреть на неё можно, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638437/183458) - возможно, натолкнёт на мысли как это всё делать.

Comment: У тебя в среднем по 320 байт на строку (на самом деле меньше), так что вряд ли можно что-то кроме массива хранить.

Comment: Для нескольких первых символов можно создать индекс. Например, при 1й букве О используются строки начиная с 1100й. При 1й букве О и 2й букве П -- строки с 1125й, а буква Р идет с 1240й (при первой О). По букве определяешь допустимый интервал (от и до). А затем посмотри реализацию `Array.binarySearch(array, from, to, stringComparator)` -- в стандартной вариации она тебе не подходит, нужно чуть подправить, т.к. тебе нужно найти не строку, а подстроку. Кроме этого, нужно заранее определить, учитывать ли регистр букв, учитывать ли дополнительные символы.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем что-то реализовывать если все уже реализовано до нас в `java.utils.Arrays`))

`public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`
пихаешь туда свой массив, даешь слово которое хочешь найти и для стринга можно компаратор указать `null`, тогда поиск будет просто юзать `Comparable` реализованный в `String`.

`Arrays.binarySearch(textArray, "or", null);`

Если ключ не найден выдаст отрицательный индекс

Comment: А если нужно первую с таким префиксом?

Comment: по документации `binarySearch` возвращает -1, если элемент не найден.